# Science Fiction book identification Series with smart-ass AI

Tags: story-identification, artificial-intelligence

Some time ago I have read book where main protagonists were helped by AI, that was real smart ass I do remember couple parts of the books so here they are:

1) 
AI is found while main protagonist is hold hostage in interrogation facility it allows main protagonist to escape confinement in to near by storage where the main character finds something resembling a tin can that is an actual AI. the AI helps him to ultimately orchestrate escape for main character and all his friends the AI is low on power and needs to be recharged so its rescue for both AI and main character

2)
later in the story we find out that the AI is in reality massive construct in different dimension while the "tin-can" is only small part that shows in normal space time.

3)
the series is with AI main character and small crew that completes different tasks one of them being attack on "carrier ship" that transports enemy sub light combat ships through FTL. They 1st capture one of the enemy parasite ships and then capture entire carrier. the main "crew" is supplemented by earth special forces

4)
the AI cheats and manipulates ppl on Earth in order to get advantage to him self and main hero, that AI consider friend. AI is also running gambling scams on Earth betting on baseball league

Comment: [Obligatory XKCD](https://xkcd.com/37) (props to Kevin for sharing it in chat).

Answer (score 10):

[*Expeditionary Force*](https://www.goodreads.com/series/185650-expeditionary-force) by Craig Alanson.

The first book in the *Expeditionary Force* series was called *Columbus Day*. The Earth was invaded by the Ruhar but were chased off by other aliens, the Kristang. Humans were conscripted to go to a planet called Paradise where they were to police the Ruhar. Joe Bishop found that the Ruhar were the good guys and ended up in a warehouse of archaeology finds from an extinct alien race called The Elders. He found an old tin can that was in fact an AI which Joe called Skippy. The bulk of Skippy's form existed in a higher spacetime and he could control how much of it bled thru to ours (effectively allowing him to change size at will). They escaped the planet by commandeering a starship called the Flying Dutchman.

Comment: Hi, this may be the right book, but it's hard for us to know for sure. Can you provide any more details to your answer, take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9445/68872) to help this user confirm this is the book without having to go hunt the internet for it. I've kicked you off with a link to goodreads, but of you could provide snippets from the text that relate to the points made by OP that would be helpful.

Comment: The first of the books in the expeditionary force series was columbus and released in Jan 2016. The AI is called skippy and the main character joe bishop. The main alien races the ruhar and the kristang. The last latest book in the series is being release on kindle on 17th nov 2017 called zero hour

Comment: This book series seems to be a lot newer than what the user is looking for, any details that suggest this is what they're wanting?

Comment: The first book in the expeditionary force series was called Columbus. The earth was invaded by the Ruhar but were chased off by other aliens the kristang. Humans were conscripted to go to a planet called Paradise where they where to police the Ruhar. Joe bishop found that the Ruhar were the good guys and ended up in a warehouse of archaeology finds from an extinct alien race called the elders. He found an old tin can that was in fact an AI which Joe called Skippy. They escaped the planet by commandeering a starship called the flying dutchman.